# Pdfkit OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found

Tags: python, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to convert a webpage to PDF, using pdfkit but it shows following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-33289a2ef087>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('H:/Python/Practice/pdf_read_write.py', wdir='H:/Python/Practice')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "H:/Python/Practice/pdf_read_write.py", line 10, in <module>
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe")

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 83, in configuration
return Configuration(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 27, in __init__
'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)

OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
```

I have downloaded wkhtmktopdf from [Here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and installed. Added the path to environment variable but still shows the same error. 
I have tried configuring pdfkit but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
import pdfkit
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
pdfkit.from_url("http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-set-2-graham-scan/", "out.pdf",configuration=config)
```

How to solve this issue ??

Comment: The `\b` in `\bin` is an [ASCII Backspace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065608/what-does-backward-slash-b-do-in-python). Try `r"C:\Program Files\..."` or `"C:\\Program Files\\..."`.

Comment: Oh !! thanks a lot !! It worked !! :D Post it as an answer. @Wondercricket

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your config path contains an [ASCII Backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065608/what-does-backward-slash-b-do-in-python), the `\b` in `\bin`, which pdfkit appears to be stripping out and converting `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe` to `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe`.

This can be resolved by using `r`, which makes it a [raw literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

```
config_path = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
```

or `\\`

```
config_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
```