# Noob Question How would I update a print a function's output without creating a new line in my term in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not exactly sure how to word this to be honest, but here's a simplified version of my current code.

```
for idx in range(0,11):
    print('Failed:',idx)
```

This outputs:

```
Failed: 0
Failed: 1
Failed: 2
Failed: 3
Failed: 4
Failed: 5
Failed: 6
Failed: 7
Failed: 8
Failed: 9
Failed: 10
```

I'm trying to replace the original int with the next int in the range instead of spamming my terminal with a new line for every int in the range.

How could I update "Failed: 1" to "Failed: 2" without creating a new line for "Failed: 2"?

Sorry if this is poorly worded, if you're willing to help me but like me to elaborate further please say so and I will try my best.

Comment: I think there is a `system.flush` method. You could also use `os.system("clear")` or  `os.system("cls")`on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is change 'Failed: 1' to 'Failed: 2', not have 'Failed: 1 Failed: 2' on the same line or new lines.

[The ASCII backslash b (backspace) helps erase characters on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065608/what-does-backward-slash-b-do-in-python). You'd want to move the cursor back to where the last number was and replace it.

Here's a simple program that moves back on the same line and replaces the counter.

```
import time
import sys

print(0, end="")
prev = 0
for i in range(20):
    print(("\b" * (len(str(prev)) + 1)), i, end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    prev = i

    time.sleep(1)
```

And to complete your example:

```
import time
import sys

last_idx = None
prefix = ''
print("Failed: ", end="")
for idx in range(0,11):
    if last_idx is not None:
        prefix = '\b' * len(str(last_idx))

    print(prefix + str(idx), end='')
    # python buffers output so you want to flush it everytime.
    sys.stdout.flush()
    last_idx = idx
    # I've added a time.sleep here so you can see it happen rather than zoom past you
    time.sleep(1)
```

Alternatively, instead of just backspacing few characters, you can go back to the beginning of the line with "carriage return" (`\r` instead of `\b`).

Comment: Thanks man, this worked perfectly for me. I also appreciate you taking the time to explain some things as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\rFailed: {}".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a second parameter that the function print takes to to specify what should print do at the end of line

```
print("Text here", end="")
```

Answer (score -1):

whoops let's  try again...

Your only option is to clear the whole console between prints. there are two ways of going about this.

option 1: You could try and use ANSI escape sequence but might be a little flakey

```
print(chr(27)+'[2j')
print('\033c')
print('\x1bc')
```

Option 2: use the os module

```
from os import system, name 
# Only on Unix
system('cls') 
# Only on windows
system('clear')
```

Comment: This does not solve problem, this only make all printed word compressed into one line, but does not remove the one printed before.