# Why is the string automatically being changed? Is it because of backslash \ in the string?

Tags: python, string, printing

Say I assign variable

```
x = '\\dnassmb1\biloadfiles_dev\Workday'
print(x)
```

Output:

```
'\\dnassmb1\x08iloadfiles_dev\\Workday'
```

I would like to know why it's changing to "x08.." specifically and how to avoid that automatic change and use string as it is. Thank you!

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065608/what-does-backward-slash-b-do-in-python

Comment: You can read the why in [String and bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals): _The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong.Backslash has a different meaning in pyhton while using in strings.
Backslashes are actually used to put some special character inside the string.
If you want to get the above string printed;

```
x = '\\\dnassmb1\\biloadfiles_dev\\Workday'
print(x)
```

If you got this, i am using an extra backslash everywhere where i want a backslash to be printed. This is because the first backslash indicates that what ever is going to come after it is just a part of the string and has no special meaning.

Comment: I think my answer worked for you. Mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw strings:

```
x = r'\\dnassmb1\biloadfiles_dev\Workday'
```

This will prevent python from treating your backslashes as escape sequences. See [string and byte literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) in the Python documentation for a full treatment of string parsing.

It's important to pay close attention to the difference between *representation* and *value* here. Just because a string appears to have four backslashes in it, doesn't mean that those backslashes are in the value of the string. Consider:

```
>>> x =  '\\dnassmb1\biloadfiles_dev\Workday'  # regular string
>>> y = r'\\dnassmb1\biloadfiles_dev\Workday'  # raw string
>>> print(x); print(y)
\dnassmbiloadfiles_dev\Workday
\\dnassmb1\biloadfiles_dev\Workday
```

Here, x and y are both just strings, once Python has parsed them. But even though the parts inside the quotes are the same, the bytes of the string are different. In `y`'s case, you see exactly the number of backslashes you put in.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer! 

Output is: '\\\\dnassmb1\\biloadfiles_dev\\Workday'

Is there a way to make it exactly '\\' slashes than 4 haha?

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: @TejasKrishnaReddy I updated my answer -- I think you're confusing representation with value. If you want the exact string you entered, write it as a raw string, with exactly the number of backslashes you want out.