# Why does a \ change what is in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.11

I recently noticed that the symbol \ behaves differently in a python string than other characters.

For example: `print('ab' + '\cde')` prints `ab\cde` as expected, but `print('a'+'\bcde')` only prints `cde`.

I was wondering what the reason for this was.
I am currently using python 11, so it may be a glitch with the new version? Only thing I can think of so far.

Comment: Not only Python. Most programming languages use \ for escape sequences. `\n` is used for newlines for example. This isn't a glitch or a new change

Comment: [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp#:~:text=To%20insert%20characters%20that%20are,character%20you%20want%20to%20insert.)

Comment: Yup, makes sense, just seemed weird when encountered in the wild.

Comment: In second print '\b' is being treated as backspace character escape sequence, hence you are getting the output as cde. if you want to print it, you can use print('a'+'\\bcde')

Comment: Note that \c doesn't show this behaviour, because it's not an escape sequence. Python then chooses to print this as normal. Try `print('a\tb')`, resulting in a tab inserted, or `print('a\ub')`, which prints a\ub as "normal". \v, vertical tab, is perhaps one of the more confusing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character is used for escape sequences in many programming languages, including Python. Here's a link to [python's escape sequences](https://pythonguides.com/escape-sequence-in-python/) if you wanted to see some of them.

The reason

```py
print('a'+'\bcde')
```

only prints

```py
cde
```

is because `\b` is the escape sequence for a backspace character. So it will move back one character (backspace), and the next character printed, `c`, overwrites the `a`. If you need to print a `\` character, use `\\`. However, as you noticed

```py
print('ab' + '\cde')
```

does not have a similar effect, and instead prints

```py
ab\cde
```

This is because `\c` is not an escape sequence, and instead, Python will print the string the way it is.

Resources:

- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp#:%7E:text=To%20insert%20characters%20that%20are,character%20you%20want%20to%20insert.)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065608/what-does-backward-slash-b-do-in-python)
- [Python Guides](https://pythonguides.com/escape-sequence-in-python/)

Comment: Right! \\ are used to escape the backslash character itself

Comment: Not entirely correct: \b moves back one character, but it will not delete the a. But by moving back one character, the c overwrites the a. Try `print("a\b")`: the a is still printed.

Comment: Just added that!